# filter json for matching schedule

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following json, how do I filter it to extract and return the relevant objects where that object's session matches the current time "now" to the next 3 hours?  (Meaning, if my current time is `23 May 2013 9 am`, objects 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 will be returned.)

Would using a library like `JSONPath` - http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ - work more efficiently?

```
    var schedule_list = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'John',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1000",
                    end: "11000"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1300",
                    end: "1500"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Mary',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1000",
                    end: "11000"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1300",
                    end: "1500"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Peter',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1000",
                    end: "11000"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1300",
                    end: "1500"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Joe',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1000",
                    end: "11000"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1300",
                    end: "1500"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Max',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1600",
                    end: "1700"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'Tom',
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    date: "23-May-2013",
                    start: "1200",
                    end:  "1300"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I am looking for a generic solution for datetime object comparison. Not simply a string based comparison. Essentially, my "current time" can be changed by a user and the date, start, end dates and times (in my JSON) returned by a server can all be variable.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xCsK3/2/

basically, what does the work is this code:

```
//get the current time and replace whitespaces with '-'
var currentTime = "23-May-2013-9-am";
for(var x = 0; x <schedule_list.length; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < schedule_list[x].sessions.length; y++){
        //check if current sessions obj time, is substring of current time
        if(currentTime.indexOf(schedule_list[x].sessions[y].date) > -1)
           console.log("x = "+x+", y = "+y+", date = "+schedule_list[x].sessions[y].date);
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I am looking for a **generic solution** for datetime object comparison. Not simply a comparison of date string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) which extends the global object JSON with the search method. Using this method, you can query JSON structures with XPath expressions (XPath is standardised query language while JSONPath isn't).

The search method returns the matches in an array (empty array if no matches were found).
Here is a jsfiddle of the code below;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/6KLMv/

```
var data = [ ... ],
    res = JSON.search( data, //sessions[date="23-May-2013" and start>="0900" and start<="1200"]/.. );

for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    console.log( res[i].id );
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 6
```

It is as generic as it gets :)